# Copying a Google Sheets file doesn't copy the old file's macros? How do I

Tags: pointers, google-sheets, macros, copy

This time last year, my hard drive crashed and I had to buy a new PC. I've used Excel 2002 for many years, so I got out the CDs and installed it on the new machine.
Unfortunately, the update packs are no longer available, so the macros I used for my accounting no longer work. So, I converted my spreadsheet to Google Sheets, and successfully rewrote several of my macros. So far, so good.

But this year, when I copied last year's accounting spreadsheet and attempted to update the macros, I discovered that the new copy was still using last year's spreadsheet macros. Try as I might, I can't access the new spreadsheet's macros, which suggests that they didn't get copied.

My questions: (1) how do I make a copy of last year's macros for use (and modification) with this year's accounting spreadsheet? (2) How do I point the new spreadsheet copy to the new macros' copy? (3) Maybe the answer is to somehow delete the new sheet's pointer to the old macros, record a new (empty) macro, then copy the old macros as text and paste 'em into the new script?

Thanks, as always.

Comment: My quick-and-dirty testing  indicates that macro **ARE** copied with the new sheet. However, the name of the Project is always the same as the project from the "copied" sheet, and perhaps this is cause confusion. 1) Please edit your question to explain EXACTLY what you mean by `I discovered that the new copy was still using last year's spreadsheet macros.` 2) ` Try as I might, I can't access the new spreadsheet's macros` Have you tried, in the new sheet,  "Main menu > "Extensions" > "Macros" > "Manage macros", then click the "Kebab" (three vertical dots), and select `Edit script`.

Comment: You're RIGHT, Tedinoz. The copied sheet's macros are named the same, but they are different copies. I opened the old sheet and its' macros as you showed, then opened the new sheet and its' macros (modified), then compared the two macro files. Although the names are the same, the two files ARE DIFFERENT. How strange! How confusing! ...yet another Google quirk.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Now, I can hover over the name and a "Rename" button pops up. I will definitely do it.